# How can I enhance the functionality of a page whose source I shouldn't modify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

A friend of mine uses a web-app for work related purposes. 
The app's built using PHP/MySQL , and while it has some JavaScript to make it easier to work with, it's not user friendly enough, and with a bit of extra JS, a lot of stuff could be automated.

I would like to enhance that app, but I'd like to not have to modify the original server-side code. To do this, all I could think of was Greasemonkey. Is this the only way to do it, or am I missing out something? I'd also like to be able to use a modern JS framework, like jQuery.

EDIT: I should tell you what improvements I want to make. There are a lot of fields on the page, so autocompletion would really help a lot. This will be used for data entering, so AJAX may be used for some error checking as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greasemonkey is certainly an option. Another idea is to code up your improvements, and then make [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) out of them. Your friend can use the bookmarks (probably in a bookmark bar) to do the things you've improved. Bookmarklets have access to the page as though they were a part of the page.

**Edit 1** In fact, now I think about it, a bookmarklet *should* be able to load a script file (from a different origin) into a document by adding a `script` tag to the `head` section (well, or anywhere, really). Since the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is based on where the *document* came from, not the script, ...  That way, he'd just have to press the button once (for any given page he goes to) to load your improvements.

**Edit 2** Yup, a bookmarklet can be used to bootstrap any script file into the page; here's an example:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20d=document,db=d.body||d.documentElement,elm;elm=d.createElement('script');elm.src="http://example.com/yourscript.js";db.appendChild(elm);db.removeChild(elm);})();
```

That adds a `script` element for the file `http://example.com/yourscript.js` to the body of the current document, which executes it. (The bookmarklet then removes the `script` element; just adding it is enough, it doesn't have to stick around; [details](http://proto-scripty.wikidot.com/prototype:how-to-load-scripts-dynamically).) Your script can then do things like add other scripts (jQuery, in your example) in the same sort of way, fire up auto-completers, etc. Tested the above (which probably needs tuning) with Chrome and Firefox; IE isn't liking it but I think that's an issue with my encoding of the bookmarklet or something rather than a fundamental problem. (I'm relatively new to bookmarklets.)

Comment: Yeah, but what if I'd like autocompletion support? I don't think they will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think Javascript can manipulate across frames, can't it?

Can't you just make a page that loads the original site in one frame and your js interface improvements in another?

(Getting the permission of the employer is also a good idea, if thats not been addressed)

Comment: Not if they aren't from the same origin, no: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: If he has the permission of the employer and the improvements are compelling, then he might be able to get the framed page served from the same server without modifying any original source.